# Terminology for the reverse of a group element's string representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, terminology

Consider a group $A$ generated by elements $a_0,a_1,...,a_k$.

Now consider element $x\in A$ given by some product of group elements under the group operation $*$. For example, $x$ may be equal to $a_9*a_5*a_1*a_9*a_9$. The reverse of the string of elements in the product, in this case, is $a_9*a_9*a_1*a_5*a_9$.

Clearly, this "reverse" of $x$ is in $A$, but does it have a name? Is there popular terminology for such an element?

Comment: It may be called the inverse of the inverse elements, i.e., $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ reverses the word $ab$, but with inverse elements. I have seen the word "reverse word" or backwards word"

Comment: It should be noted that this operation really only makes sense in the set of words of elements (i.e., in the free monoid) not in the group per se. For example, let $b=a_5*a_1$. Then the result of $a_9*b*a_9*a_9$ is $a_9*a_9*b*a_9$ and usually $a_9*a_9*b*a_9\ne a_9*a_9*a_1*a_5*a_9$ even though $a_9*b*a_9*a_9=a_9*a_5*a_1*a_9*a_9$. -- And in the free monoid over any set (e.g., the set of group elements), one certainly speaks of the reverse or backwards word, as also mentioned by @DietrichBurde

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If the product only consists of generator elements, does the operation still not make sense?

Comment: It makes sense if every element has a unique representation as a word over the given generating set. If this is not the case, you'd need some other argument to justify that the result is well-defined.

Comment: Surely there's a word for this in [tag:formal-languages].